# stackoverflow error when I add a glasspane to my frame

Tags: java, swing, stack-overflow

I am trying to add a universal right click to textfields in my application. I came across a solution where I could add a glass pane on top my frame, make it invisible and register that as a universal mouse listener. If the component is a text field I show the pop up menu,  otherwise I redispatch the event. I have pasted the code below...

This example works fine. But when I use this with my application though, I get a stackoverflow error at

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at apple.awt.CWindow._getLocationOnScreen(Native Method)
at apple.awt.CWindow.getLocationOnScreen(CWindow.java:878)
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:1960)
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:1938)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(SwingUtilities.java:364)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.convertPoint(SwingUtilities.java:165)
at com.aesthete.csmart.ui.common.components.RightClickGlassPane.redispatchMouseEvent(RightClickGlassPane.java:79)
at com.aesthete.csmart.ui.common.components.RightClickGlassPane.mouseEntered(RightClickGlassPane.java:61)
```

**I understand that every time the mouse is entered on a component the glass pane receives the event and then redispatches. But why is it getting converted into a recursive call?**

**EDIT:**
Just wanted to show everyone how I solved it with Camickr suggestion:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
            JMenuItem mnItemCopy = new JMenuItem("Copy", CommonUI.getScaledImage(13, 13, "/images/copy.png"));
            JMenuItem mnItemCut = new JMenuItem("Cut", CommonUI.getScaledImage(13, 13, "/images/cut.png"));
            JMenuItem mnItemPaste = new JMenuItem("Paste", CommonUI.getScaledImage(13, 13, "/images/paste.png"));
            popup.add(mnItemCopy);
            popup.add(mnItemCut);
            popup.add(mnItemPaste);

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                    if(event instanceof MouseEvent) {
                        MouseEvent mouseevent=(MouseEvent)event;
                        if(mouseevent.isPopupTrigger()) {
                            if (mouseevent.getComponent() instanceof JTextField) {
                                popup.show(mouseevent.getComponent(), mouseevent.getX(), mouseevent.getY());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
        }
    });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note that there are now **2 deleted posts** based on the code that did not display the problem!  That same code has now been edited out of the question, to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Sorry about the incorrect SSCCE. I used the same class I posted in my code base. I extracted that out and saw that it was running correctly. I wasn't sure why it was failing when integrated with my code base. Thought I'll put all the information I had.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  Down-vote reversed - for reporting the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to add a universal right click to textfields in my application.

Check out [Global Event LIsteners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/). Just check the source of the event and do processing as required. No need to redispatch events.

Note, you should NOT assume a right click is the LAF way to display a popup. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for a better solution.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, correct, I edited the answer to add the NOT.